# how to add a new option to context menu of hyperlink in an email for Outlook 2010?

Tags: c#-4.0, outlook

I did add a new menuitem to that hyperlink context menu. Now I need to find the hyperlink I right-clicked.

What I got is the whole email item from Office.IRibbonControl.Context, which is an Outlook.Explorer with one Selection. The selection turns out to be an OutlookItem.

It does have an email body. But I may have multiple hyperlinks in inside it. It must be a way to get the hyperlink because other menu items work: Open, Select, Copy Hyperlink.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Sunday has passed, sorry. But I´ve had the same problem and found the following solution:

```
    public void OnCustomHyperlinkMenuClick(IRibbonControl control)
    {
        Explorer explorer = control.Context as Explorer;
        if (explorer != null)
        {
            Document document = explorer.ActiveInlineResponseWordEditor;
            if (document != null && document.Windows != null && document.Windows.Count > 0)
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Selection selection = document.Windows[1].Selection;
                if (selection != null && selection.Hyperlinks != null && selection.Hyperlinks.Count > 0)
                {
                    Hyperlink hyperlink = selection.Hyperlinks[1];
                    string hyperlinkUrl = hyperlink.Address;
                    DoSomethingWithUrl(hyperlinkUrl);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You will need to add a reference to the word interop assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll" to your outlook add in project.